# Google maps infowindow share same lat/long

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I was helped out by an SO member with the following code which allows me to use multiple markers from a PHP array and plot them on a map:

```
    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) 
    { 

  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][0], locations[i][1]),
    map: map
   });


  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() 
    {

      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][2]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
    }
```

So that code is grabbing my array and putting my markers on the map and in the infowindow, printing out the customer name.
I quickly came across an issue however.  If a customer share's the same lat/long (they're derived from postcode), only one of the customers appear - e.g. Customer1 at LN1 7HQ and Customer2 at LN1 7HQ, only customer 1 will appear in the info window.
A few solutions I found include clustering markers and offsetting them - but what I would like is the have 1 infowindow for each postcode and then list the customers located there in the window.
I haven't found a way to do it but would assume it will involve altering the For loop below and adding something like "If lat, long === lat, long, then locations[i][2] ++ ..." but I'm just about grasping PHP and javascript is still new to me.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If I understand properly: if you have 10 customers from the same location you want to open one marker with one infowindow which contains information about 10 customers' name.

Comment: absolutely Anto.  The customer name is pulled into the same php array as the lat/long (hence location[i][0]..[i][2].  I would want to add more into this array (i.e. phone number, maybe a rating system later) - but the principle is to have all of this in one info window when the customer shares the same postcode (i.e. lat/long). Just for clarity, positions in the array are: [0] Lat, [1] Long, [2] Customer Name.

Comment: As another update to this - I've been attempting to try a little logic in the javascript along the lines of : var content = location[2]; if (location[0] == location[0] && location[1] == location[1]) {content = content + "<p>" + content} ... parphrased but I hope you can see what I'm attempting.  So far there's no joy.  Still cracking on with it but not seeing the solution as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution: track created markers using array

```
var markers = [];
```

with information about location indexes using following object:

```
function MarkerInfo(marker, idx) {
    this.marker    = marker;
    this.locations = [idx];
}
```

There are two loops. The 1st loop build array of `MarkerInfo` with marker and list of indexes from `locations` array. The 2nd loop prepares content string for infowindow and creates listeners.

See [example at jsbin](http://jsbin.com/sevij/1/edit).

**Note:** for the future changes: solution won't work properly if you change `locations` array with information about customers between those two loops.

Comment: thanks for that Anto - I did try to get this working but struggled a bit - It's PHP which creates the marker, lat, long array (and any additional info I want to pull in later) - I couldn't figure out how to add it to another array and iterate through it.  In the meantime I was looking into another solution - offsetting the markers by 10 meters or so - my requirement doesn't need to be pin point accurate and only a handful of clients will share the same location - tried a few solutions to make an offset but couldn't get that working either - trouble I'm having is re-engineering my code to fit.